# Displacement result has sharp edges

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, sculpting, displacement

I wanted to do a simple test on a cube. I created uvs, added a mlutires modifier, and did some sculpting. Then I baked a displacement map, following Royal Skies tutorial. But it doesn't really displace the cube properly.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Sculpted cube
[image]

Cube with displacement
[image]

Node tree
[image]

Displacement
[image]

Displacement set to 0.1
[image]

[4K image of the displacement here](https://i.ibb.co/NyQDzm3/Disp-Test-01.png)

> Blendfile: https://pasteall.org/blend/62d9ac2afea048e68e426552e7c9bc0d

Comment: Hello :). Just a guess, but perhaps try lowering the displacement Scale value? It's now set to meters, which may be too much. Lowering to 0,01 could help

Comment: I  edited and added a render of what it look like with the displacement set to 0.1, I can still see the sharp edge, but not the actual details that I sculpted.

Comment: hello, could you please pack the image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I put the scene and the image into a zip file, and it's been uploading for the last 10 minutes. It's 18mb, so I'm not sure why it's taking so long. Is there another way to upload the scene file?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/62d9ac2afea048e68e426552e7c9bc0d here is the blend file. the displacement image is in the post now.